# C# TagLib Set Album Cover for Mp3

Tags: c#, mp3, taglib, id3, cover

I have an mp3 file and I want to add the album art to it. The art has been saved into a temp folder, I have check this and it is there and is a jpeg.
This is the code I gave:

```
        public void AddMp3Tags()
        {
            TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(OutputPath + OutputName + "." + Format);
            SetAlbumArt(Art, file);
            file.Tag.Title = SongTitle;
            file.Tag.Performers = Artists.Split(',');
            file.Tag.Album = Album;           
            file.Tag.Track = (uint)TrackNumber;
            file.Tag.Year = (uint)Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Year, @"(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)").Value);            
            file.Save();
        }

        public void SetAlbumArt(string url, TagLib.File file)
        {     
            string path = string.Format(@"{0}temp\{1}.jpg", OutputPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {

                client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), path);
            }


            TagLib.Picture pic = new TagLib.Picture
            {
                Type = TagLib.PictureType.FrontCover,
                Description = "Cover",
                MimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg
            };
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms.Position = 0;
            pic.Data = TagLib.ByteVector.FromStream(ms);
            file.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[] { pic };
            file.Save();
            ms.Close();

        }
```

All of the tags are set correctly except the art work which just shows a black box:
[Black box cover art in windows media player.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ33p.png)

I have tried many things, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a note, won’t be the problem here. There is probably no reason to read the JPEG into an image and save it again since it causes quality loss. Just open the file and give that stream to TagLib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I did some more research and it turns out that by default WMP tries to use a web service to get album artwork, I opened the song in VLC and the artwork was shown. The album code was correctly written as shown here: [Mp3Tag Viewer/Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbJdW.png)

Another thing that I found out is that my tags were using Id3v2.4 and Id3v1. WMP does not like this for some reason so I forced TagLib to use Id3v2.3. I also changed the text encoding to UFT16 because UFT8 wasn't working. The album art is now showing in WMP and windows explorer.

I also found a way not to write the image to the disk by downloading the data from the web page and saving it to memory.

This was my final code:

```
public void AddMp3Tags()
{
    TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.DefaultVersion = 3;
    TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.ForceDefaultVersion = true;
    TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(OutputPath + OutputName + ".mp3");
    SetAlbumArt(Art, file);
    file.Tag.Title = SongTitle;
    file.Tag.Performers = Artists.Split(',');
    file.Tag.Album = Album;           
    file.Tag.Track = (uint)TrackNumber;
    file.Tag.Year = (uint)Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Year, @"(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)").Value);
    file.RemoveTags(file.TagTypes & ~file.TagTypesOnDisk);
    file.Save();
}

public void SetAlbumArt(string url, TagLib.File file)
{            
    string path = string.Format(@"{0}temp\{1}.jpg", OutputPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    byte[] imageBytes;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        imageBytes = client.DownloadData(url);
    }

    TagLib.Id3v2.AttachedPictureFrame cover = new TagLib.Id3v2.AttachedPictureFrame
    {
        Type = TagLib.PictureType.FrontCover,
        Description = "Cover",
        MimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg,
        Data = imageBytes,
        TextEncoding = TagLib.StringType.UTF16


    };
    file.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[] { cover };
}
```

I hope this helps anyone that has the same problem as me and doesn't need to spend as much time figuring this out as I did.

Comment: Not sure why you need all that code. I added the pic in 1 line and it worked fine in WMP and VLC with no problems (without changing tag versions) >>>>>  
file.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[] { new TagLib.Picture(@"c:\temp\mycover.png") };

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your file downloaded successfully and try this:

```
public void SetAlbumArt(string url, TagLib.File file)
{     
    string path = string.Format(@"{0}temp\{1}.jpg", OutputPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {

        client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), path);
    }

    file.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[]
    {
        new TagLib.Picture(new TagLib.ByteVector((byte[])new System.Drawing.ImageConverter().ConvertTo(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path), typeof(byte[]))))
        {
            Type = TagLib.PictureType.FrontCover,
            Description = "Cover",
            MimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg
        }
    };

    file.Save();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still did not work, and the image file is definitely downloaded as I can see it in the folder.

Comment: Make sure jpeg file is in correct format. May be bitmap image with '.jpg' extension. open your jpeg file with paint and save as with different name (for test).

Comment: This was no the issue. But thanks anyway. I have solved my problem now.