# set artist image for an audio(mp3) c#?

Tags: c#, audio, thumbnails

All of the songs has a artist image, but how to read that from a file? and how to edit that artist image for an audio?

but there's no library for audios in c#(Or I didn't found)
I searched on the internet, but there was no good resource about audio files.

Comment: Audio in general or mp3 in particular?

Comment: For me mp3, but I don't mind if it works for other extensions.

Comment: Did you have a look into these: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50437358/982149 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/349581/982149 ?

Comment: That actually answers my question. I just searched thumbnail and I didn't see these questions. I had to edit the question, so it doesn't get closed